# Why does this String.split() split my string?

Tags: java

Why this code does not work?

```
String s = "0.1";
String[] sa = s.split(".");
System.out.println(sa[0] + "Hello " + sa[1]);
```

It gives the error as :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at com.test.A.main(A.java:8)
```

Comment: Try `"\\."` instead of "." which means any character.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey i want to delete my question :( :( :( :( . You guys are so strict

Comment: Why was this voted down? If you don't know that `String.split` takes a regex as an argument, and assume (carelessly but reasonably) that it takes a string to match exactly, then there's no obvious leap from the error observed here to the correct cause. I don't think this question is idiotic.

Comment: @Thinker.. You should rather concentrate on learning new things here rather than worrying about down-votes. Don't get discouraged by this. In fact, I also think that downvote on this question is not fair, but it should no way be any criteria to delete questions. Plus we expect posters to do some research before posting questions, so that we know that you are making some efforts on your part.

Comment: @MarkAmery SO also expects people to read the Javadoc as a minimum prerequisite before asking ("question shows research effort").

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Or using google, but not everyone knows to read the docs or try google first. ;)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Effort: the OP got the question down to a 3-line demonstration of the problem he was experiencing before posting, which allowed it to be solved instantly by the answerers. Yes, as it turns out he was just one further step away from solving his own problem - if he'd gone to the Javadoc he would've seen a mention of these mysterious 'regular expressions' that he'd perhaps never seen before, followed the link, and solved his own problem - but he *did* do some work here. I suspect if he'd dumped 100 lines of code instead of trimming down to 3, there'd be no downvotes - perversely.

Comment: @MarkAmery You must be new around here... mountain-of-code questions are a perfect downvote-bait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) doesn't split the string by another string, it splits it by a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). The `.` has a special meaning in regular expression (it stands for "any character"). So when you want to explicitely match dots, you need to escape them. Use `"\\."` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
 String[] sa = s.split("\\.");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
String[] sa = s.split("\\.");
```

The `.` dot is a special regex character and will match anything unless you escape it.

Your `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs because you exceed the bounds of your array.

The way you had it `sa.length` would be 0, so any array access would cause your Exception.

Answer (score 1):

split is regex based. see the second paragraph [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0438.html)

in short. the answer is escaping, as in

```
split("\\.")
```

Answer (score 0):

escape `"."` - it is treated as special character. You might want to read [this](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=96).

```
String[] sa = s.split("\\.");
```